# Disconnections on Photon PUN2

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

It's been two years since I've been having problems with my game using Photon PUN2, where around 90% of the crashes are due to disconnections that happen with the Photon server, recently I did a test by turning off the wifi during the game and turning it back on afterwards of a few seconds and it ended up freezing the game due to disconnection, this wifi connection was 10mb. Another test I did with 100mb WiFi and using mobile data from my cell phone, which, turning it off and on, didn't stop the game.

| Connection Type | Speed | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Wifi | <15mb | Crash Bug |
| Mobile Internet | 10 - 50mb | Don't crash |
| Wifi | >40mb | Don't crash |

This has been going on for two years and I don't know what else to do. I have already followed several of their documentation

Carrying out a multiplayer game where players did not connect to the server so often, and when there was a disconnection of a player he could reconnect